# Accept a path as literal path, relative path or relative to the script root

Tags: powershell, path

Currently we want to cover these 3 cases when retrieving file information:

- A literal path
- A relative path, relative to the script root
- A relative path, relative to the present working directory

To cover these 3 cases we created the following function:

```bsh
Function Get-FilePathItemHC {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$Path
    )

    $Params = @(
        @{
            # Path relative to the script root
            LiteralPath = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath $Path
        }
        @{
            # Literal or path relative to the present work directory
            Path = $Path
        }
    )

    $Item = $null

    foreach ($P in $Params) {
        if ($Item = Get-Item @P -ErrorAction Ignore) {
            $Item
            Break
        }
    }

    if (-not $Item) {
        throw "Cannot find path '$Path' because it does not exist."
    }
}
```

Is this the right way of doing it? It seems like we're reinventing the wheel here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `-Path` Parameter a `System.IO.FileInfo` object, and just pass in a relative path as the parameter. The file object will resolve with either a relative or full path, then you can use `$path.FullName` to reference the full path to the file.

```
Function Get-FilePathItemHC {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateScript({ $_.Exists })]
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$Path
    )

    # The ValidateScript attribute makes sure the file you passed in exists
    # so your validation code no longer is required
}
```

If you want to handle both directories and files, you would want to have two separate variables in this case as directory paths would become a `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` object, but you can make the arguments mutually exclusive:

```
Function Get-FilePathItemHC {
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="FilePath")]
    [ValidateScript({ $_.Exists })]
    [System.IO.FileInfo]$FilePath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="DirectoryPath")]
    [ValidateScript({ $_.Exists })]
    [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$DirectoryPath
)

  $Path = $FilePath
  if( $DirectoryPath ) {
    $Path = $DirectoryPath
  }

  # The ValidateScript attribute makes sure the file you passed in exists
  # so your validation code no longer is required
}

Get-FilePathItemHC -Path .\path\to\file.txt
```

## Get the relative path from `$PSScriptRoot`

I'm not sure why you need the path relative to `$PSScriptRoot` if you already have the full path to the file, but after getting the `System.IO.FileInfo` or `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` object, you can use `Resolve-Path` from `$PSScriptRoot` to get the relative path from that directory:

```
$file = Get-FilePathItemHC -Path .\path\to\file.txt
Push-Location $PSScriptRoot
$relativeFromScriptRootPath = Resolve-Path -Relative $file
Pop-Location
```

`Push-Location` and `Pop-Location` treat the location as a stack. The `push` operation sets a new location and adds it to the stack, and the `pop` operation removes the last added location from the stack and places you at the next most recent location. Works a bit like `cd -` on Linux if you're familiar.

`Resolve-Path` will return a file path, and the `-Relative` switch will return a path relative to your current directory. You cannot pass in an alternate directory to resolve from, which is why we change the location to run this.

Comment: Thank you @Bender but the thing I'm trying to find out is the path relative to the script root folder, a regular relative path or a literal path. You're code wont cover the first case I'm afraid.

Comment: See my updated answer for using `Resolve-Path` to get the relative path from `$PSScriptRoot`

Comment: Never heard about `Push-Location` and `Pop-Location`. Great tip, thanks! :)

Comment: In my `$profile`, I've actually aliasesd `cd` to `Push-Location` and aliased `pd` to `Pop-Location`. My solution to the lack of `cd -` without having to use the full cmdlet names or longer aliases of `pushd` and `popd`